# how to subscribe with rosbridge

Tags: ros, rosbridge

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hello guys,
i'm new at ros. i want to subscribe a topic to a webpage. i tried to do the following tutorial but subscribe part doesnt work. Should i add a label or something to view the subscription to the html file?
here is the tutorial:
http://wiki.ros.org/roslibjs/Tutorials/BasicRosFunctionality

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/208440/how-to-subscribe-with-rosbridge/) by [minerva](https://answers.ros.org/users/21509/minerva/) on ROS Answers with karma: 18 on 2015-05-03

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [corb](https://answers.ros.org/users/20674/corb/) on 2015-05-03**:
what do you see in the browser console?

**Comment by [minerva](https://answers.ros.org/users/21509/minerva/) on 2015-05-04**:
what do you mean by browser console? i just open html file.

**Comment by [corb](https://answers.ros.org/users/20674/corb/) on 2015-05-04**:
You need to save the html code to a file, like "ros_test.html".  Then open that file in your browser.  You should see "Simple roslib Example.  Check your Web Console for output".    To see the console (in the Chrome browser):   menu/more tools/javascript console.  Other browsers will be similar.

**Comment by [minerva](https://answers.ros.org/users/21509/minerva/) on 2015-05-05**:
oh "Received message on /listener: Hello wold" is written there thank you :)  so the code is ok but how can i write it to a label?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to save the html code to a file, like ros_test.html. Then open that file in your browser. You should see Simple roslib Example. Check your Web Console for output. To see the console (in the Chrome browser): menu, more tools, javascript console. Other browsers will have something similar.

To have the HTML update:
In the body section, add something with an Id:

```
  <body>
  <h1>Simple roslib Example</h1>
  <p id="abc">Test</p>
</body>
```

In listener.subscribe(function(message), add

```
document.getElementById("abc").innerHTML = message.data;
```

---

Originally posted by [corb](https://answers.ros.org/users/20674/corb/) with karma: 339 on 2015-05-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [minerva](https://answers.ros.org/users/21509/minerva/) on 2015-05-05**:
it helped thank you! :)